# how to change several piece of html code

Tags: python, html, perl, text-processing

I have the following lines in html pages

```
    <td style="color:#8C8C8C;font-size:10px;font-family:Arial,'Helvetica';text-align:center; padding:0 15px 0 15px;">Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant reteuteu@cab05.net a votre carnet d'adresses.<br />
Si vous avez des difficult&eacute;s pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur <a style="color:#8C8C8C;" target="_blank" href="#"><u>cette page</u></a>.</td>
```

I need to replace the above with only

```
[{test}]
```

or like this one

```
href="#">reteuteu.fr
```

And replace it with:

```
href="http://mm.eulerian.net/dynclick/reteuteu/?eml-publisher=reteuteu&eml-name=deme_faible&eemail={email}&eurl=https://www.reteuteu.fr/?utm_source=ANIM&utm_medium=Targeting&utm_campaign=deme_faible&utm_term=CCCC_seg_men&utm_content=website">reteuteu.fr
```

I've tried to keep it simple by using simple bash tools like this : `sed -e 's~SEARCH_STRING~REPLACE_STRING~g' <string_to_be_searched>`

Issue is sed works well for string that has one line but it bugs when I have line feed or metacharacters like `&`.

I heard python or perl can do the trick but I have no idea how to do it.

Ultimately I want to be run it in this way

```
python script.py STRING_TO_SEARCH_WITH_LINE_FEED_OR_META_CHARACTERS STRING_TO_BE_REPLACE
```

or

```
perl script.pl STRING_TO_SEARCH_WITH_LINE_FEED_OR_META_CHARACTERS STRING_TO_BE_REPLACE
```

I read about HTQL or HTML parser but I need hints on how to do it.

Many thanks for any clues you can give me.

*Expected output would be like this for the first example*

```
<td style="color:#8C8C8C;font-size:10px;font-family:Arial,'Helvetica';text-align:center; padding:0 15px 0 15px;">[{test}] <a style="color:#8C8C8C;" target="_blank" href="#"><u>cette page</u></a>.</td>
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through Perl.

```
$ perl -0777pe "s/<td style=\"color:#8C8C8C;font-size:10px;font-family:Arial,'Helvetica';text-align:center; padding:0 15px 0 15px;\">\K.*?(?=<a\b)/[{test}] /sg" file
    <td style="color:#8C8C8C;font-size:10px;font-family:Arial,'Helvetica';text-align:center; padding:0 15px 0 15px;">[{test}] <a style="color:#8C8C8C;" target="_blank" href="#"><u>cette page</u></a>.</td>
```

[`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final. `\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match. So the previously matched `<td>` tag is discarded. Then this `.*?` matches all the characters upto the beginning of `a` tag . Here `.` matches also the line breaks because we used DOTALL modifier `s`. `(?=<a\b)` positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by `<a` and a `\b` boundary.

`-0777` turns the Record Separator value to null, thus allowing the regex to match the line breaks.

Comment: just wow. Can you explain a bit please , especially the `\K.*?(?=<a\b)` ? What does this mean?

Comment: I've got even more questions: 

How does the script know , it should only encompass the message **below** and stop when it sees this part `<a style="color:#8C8C8C;" target="_blank" href="#"><u>cette page</u></a>.</td>`

**The message** 

`Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant reteuteu@cab05.net a votre carnet d'adresses.<br />
Si vous avez des difficult&eacute;s pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur`

Comment: I feel like dumb ... -_-

Comment: did you want to do the same for all the td tags which was followed by an anchor tag?

Comment: I only wanted to remove the message `Assurez-vous de bien recevoir tous nos messages en ajoutant reteuteu@cab05.net a votre carnet d'adresses.<br /> Si vous avez des difficult&eacute;s pour visualiser ce message, rendez-vous sur` . So you did fine. I'm just confused on how you did it.

Comment: Because the message is unique but the rest of html code can be more common. Does it make sense?

Comment: like i said before, `<td style=\"color:#8C8C8C;font-size:10px;font-family:Arial,'Helvetica';text-align:center; padding:0 15px 0 15px;\">` part in my regex matches exactly the same part in your file then the upcommimg `\K` discards this match and now the regex pointer is exists next to the discarded boundary. ie, the marker is next to `15px;\">` string. Now `.*?` matches all the remaining characters upto the `a` tag. Finally the perl replaces all the matched characters with `[{test}]`

Comment: Done sir. Thanks again. I need to check about Perl. This is definitely what I need to use most of the time in order to deal with strings replacement.

Comment: one question because i'm curious. Would it be easy to do that with python?